# How does an audio converter work?

Tags: audio

I currently have the idea to code a small audio converter (e.g. FLAC to MP3 or m4a format) application in C# or Python but my problem is I do not know at all how audio conversion works.

After a research, I heard about Analog-to-digital / Digital-to-analog converter but I guess it would be a Digital-to-digital or something like that isn't it ?

If someone could precisely explain how it works, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

digital audio is called PCM which is the raw audio format fundamental to any audio processing system ... its uncompressed ... just a series of integers representing the height of the audio curve for each sample of the curve (the Y axis where time is the X axis along this curve)

... this PCM audio can be compressed using some codec then bundled inside a container often together with video or meta data channels ... so to convert audio from A to B you would first need to understand the container spec as well as the compressed audio codec so you can decompress audio A into PCM format ... then do the reverse ... compress the PCM into codec of B then bundle it into the container of B

Before venturing further into this I suggest you master the art of WAVE audio files ... beauty of WAVE is that its just a 44 byte header followed by the uncompressed integers of the audio curve ... write some code to read a WAVE file then parse the header (identify bit depth, sample rate, channel count, endianness) to enable you to iterate across each audio sample for each channel ... prove that its working by sending your bytes into an output WAVE file ... diff input WAVE against output WAVE as they should be identical ... once mastered you are ready to venture into your above stated goal ... do not skip over groking notion of interleaving stereo audio as well as spreading out a single audio sample which has a bit depth of 16 bits across two bytes of storage and the reverse namely stitching together multiple bytes into a single integer with a bit depth of 16, 24 or even 32 bits while keeping endianness squared away ... this may sound scary at first however all necessary details are on the net as its how I taught myself this level of detail

modern audio compression algorithms leverage knowledge of how people perceive sound to discard information which is indiscernible ( lossy ) as opposed to lossless algorithms which retain all the informational load of the source ... opus (http://opus-codec.org/) is a current favorite codec untainted by patents and is open source