# How can i convert 3gp file to mp3 without any library android

Tags: android, compression, mp3, android-mediarecorder, android-ffmpeg

I have a recording Android app in which i want to convert the 3gp audio clips to mp3 in order to send them to server. As i have searched the internet, the only way to do that is through some various libraries like
Lame, FFmpeg and others which have some restrictions on my app.

For example the `implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full:4.4'` which is the ffmpeg has minimumSdk to 24 but mine if for devices the support Android 5.

Is there a snippet of code that can do my job or at lease some kind of useful advice?
Thank you

Comment: The reason you need an external library for this is because 3gp and mp3 have entirely different audio file formats. There is no "snippet" of code to convert between audio formats.

Comment: Look at the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888430/how-does-an-audio-converter-work) question and it will give you an idea of the complexity of audio file conversion.